# SQL Script to clean the history Publication and related items in 2011 SP1 instance

Tags: 2011-sp1

Inside our Tridion 2011 instance, there are a lot of legacy publications with huge number of published components and pages. We created a C# tool based on Tridion core service API to un-publish / unlocalize / uncheckout and delete them. But the relationship is too complex and size is too big. After more than 5 days continues running there are still more than a half items not be cleaned.

Is there any SQL Script can help us safely set related item's publish status to false so we can just delete it directly?

Comment: It is achievable but probably no "safe" way to set the item's publish status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably best speaking to SDL Support about this. They are the only ones who would be able to provide a SQL script that would still leave your implementation fully supported afterwards.

Comment: Even when provided by SDL support, DB-level modifications are not supported.

Comment: Rick, that's good to know. Thanks for the information.

Comment: That's very nice to know the DB level modification is not supported. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider upgrading to SDL Web 8 (or 2013 SP1). Those versions provide functionality to "decommission" Publication Targets, i.e. to "forget" publish state of items.

Comment: Thanks Rick. If we migrate from 2011 CMS DB to WEB8 DB directly, will the publish status be kept? If not, can we just leave it like this, then delete them after migration?

Comment: For the decommission feature, will it affect all items be published to that targets? Since we have 20% publications need to be delete, but still want to keep the other 80%. They share the same publish targets.

Comment: Normally, decommissioning applies to all Publicatioms, but IIRC you can create an event handler to interfere with the resolving.